# Things between Maximum Likelihood Estimation and Ordinary Least Squares?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, data-mining

- What are the similarities and differences between Ordinary Least Squares and Maximum Likelihood Estimation?
- Are they both parametric methods?
- If we have Ordinary Least Squares, why do we need Maximum Likelihood Estimation?
- What are the benefits of Maximum Likelihood Estimation opposed to Ordinary Least Squares?
- What does "Ordinary Least Square needs no stochastic assumption" mean?

Comment: These are all questions which you will find answers to by doing a bit of reading and googling. Also you will learn a lot more by investigating these things yourself. If you have a specific point you are confused about then people will be happy to help but currently this looks like a list of assignment questions which you should be doing yourself.

Comment: These are not my assignment questions. While I am studying MLE, those came across. I have been googling, too. Of course, I am doing it by myself, but hope to get some opinions, that's all.